# No module named fitness python import error

Tags: python, django

i'm having troubles with python importing. Here is my structure.

```
 fitness/
    __init__.py
    authentication/ 
       __init__.py
       views.py
       urls.py 
    views.py 
    urls.py
```

from authentication.views i'm trying to import the fitness.views

I've been trying to use

```py
from fitness import views
```

which eclipse reads fine, but when i run it it says

```
No module named fitness
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the directory containing the module you're trying to import (fitness.views) to the PYTHONPATH. Put this at the beginning of your module. It adds '../../' to the PYTHONPATH. That is the directory containing the fitness folder, so you can import the module without any problem.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')))
from fitness import views
```