# Importing modules from different directories

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-module

I have a problem importing a module:
It is under this directory `./dao` and the code that calls it is here `./core`. Schematically represented as:

```
rnaspace/
 __init__.py
 core/
   __init__.py
   logger.py
 dao/
   __init__.py
   storage_configuration_reader.py
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "logger.py", line 21, in <module>
    from rnaspace.dao.storage_configuration_reader import storage_configuration_reader ImportError: No module named rnaspace.dao.storage_configuration_reader
```

This file it is there `/rnaspace/dao/storage_configuration_reader.py` and in the same folder the `__init__.py` file as follows:

```
""" Package dao
    Gathers files that access to the plateform data 
"""
```

If I understood well [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260792/2886003), it should work. I think that the problem is that one is not the subdirectory of the other (or that the path is not exaclly that one), there is a way to go around it? Or need I to apply the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068198/no-module-named-fitness-python-import-error?lq=1)?

**EDIT**
The `__init__.py` file of the rnaspace folder:

```
import rnaspace.dao.storage_configuration_reader as scr

def update_conf(conf_path, predictors_conf_dir):
    scr.update_conf(conf_path, predictors_conf_dir)
```

Comment: Do you have a `__init__` file in rnaspace folder?

Comment: Take a look at [Intra-package References](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in the Python docs.

Comment: @icedtrees Edited, I have the file.
@lanzz That means that I can import my module with just `from .. import storage_configuration_reader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970947/2886003), it is using the module imp.
I just needed to add the name of the module, and the absolute path where it was:

```
imp.load_source("storage_configuration_reader","./rnaspace/dao/storage_configuration_reader.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from rnaspace.dao.storage_configuration_reader import storage_configuration_reader
```

That is wrong because there is no "storage_configuration_reader" directory in "dao" directory

This is how it should be:

```
from rnaspace.dao import storage_configuration_reader
```

**EDIT:**

or this way:

```
import rnaspace.dao.storage_configuration_reader
```

Comment: [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) seems that it can point directly to the file not to the directory, but I will try it

Comment: The second version doesn't work the first one neither. But I am not sure if it is a problem of the importation or from the program itself.

Comment: in that case try to remove special characters ("_") from name of your module. Also what error you get for my examples?

Comment: Well this comes from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21754876/2886003) is the last part of code what I am trying to repair, but the problem is on the first sections of this question. The problem is this: `test (__main__.test_athaliana) ... No handlers could be found for logger "rnaspace"` that are defined on the file it fails, to import it.
The error are still: `from rnaspace.dao import storage_configuration_reader
ImportError: No module named rnaspace.da`