# Importing modules from relative path to absolute

Tags: python, import, python-2.6, importerror, python-import

I am trying to run a program which it specification say for python 2.6 I am running it with python 2.6.6, so it should work but I found that the importation fails see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21855430/2886003), and this sample:

```
from rnaspace.dao.storage_configuration_reader import storage_configuration_reader
```

This is due to a version change (I doubt) or of some of the environment on the original server? A solution is in the question cited, but I there is another way to solve this problem that it doesn't involve to change each file with this kind of importation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import statement assumes python knows where the 'rnaspace' package is. Maybe you need to add the path to the package `rnaspace` in your include path?

```
    import sys

    pathToRnaspace = "/path/to/the/rnaspace/package"
    sys.path.append(pathToRnaspace)

    from rnaspace.core.putative_rna import putative_rna
```

Comment: Works but this implies that I must do it for each file of the program to work well...

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid that, I'm afraid. Each file would need to import the packages it uses. I'd love to know if there is a way, if I'm wrong!